# In Cassandra How In operation will work like SQL?

Tags: cassandra

My requirement is I need to fetch the records from Cassandra one column that column value is not a particular string other than the list of string which i have passed...      For example for in the data there is a column name service... That column may contain the values of 1,2,3,4,5....                                                                      I dont want to display 5... I want to display the records which has 1 or 2 or 3 or 4...                                                                                        How to achieve this... Could you please anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing 1..5 in your column as values there is no other go, You need to do it from client side only. You can't filter from cassandra end

If 1..5 itself is in your column name like

```
row_1 => { 1: value, 2:value... }
row_2 => { 1: value, 2:value... }
..
row_3 => { 1: value, 2:value... }
```

then you can use

```
SELECT 1..4 from YOUR_COLUMN_FAMILY where key='yourKey'
```

As an other option if you can have 1..5 as separate rows like

```
1 => { c1: value, c2:value... }
2 => { c1: value, c2:value... }
..
5 => { c1: value, c2:value... }
```

you can do

```
SELECT * from YOUR_COLUMN_FAMILY where key in (1,2,3,4)
```

You can also have a look @secondary Indexes on columns [here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/dml/using_cql#indexing-a-column)

> Because of the secondary index created on the columns, their
>   values can be queried directly